# GAS standalone app: Is there a way to create a document without an association with any google account?

Tags: google-apps-script

If I have a standalone app which uses this piece of code:

```
function createDuplicateDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DocsList.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name);
    return DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());
}
```

And this app is open to everyone to use it, when the new document is created, where the document will be placed? Is there a way to create a document without an association with any google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deployed the app to run as you, the document will be created in your drive, if you deployed it to run as "the user executing the app" then it will be created in this user's drive.

There is no way to change that... The only thing you can do is to change ownership properties of the newly created document. This can be done with a Library developed by [Romain Vialard](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice) if you are working inside a domain and have admin rights.

Otherwise you can only change [sharing properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).

Comment: So, a way to deal with it could be create the new document, allow the user download it as pdf or word, and, after some time (1 hour, 1 day, maybe) to automatically delete the document (with a time trigger which deletes all documents of a folder owned by you). What do you think?

Comment: You could preferably send it as a mail attachment... users are often kind of lazy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to create a document without any association to any Google account.  But you would need to save the file to some other internet service, or the user would need to download it to their computer.  To save the file to some other online service, you'd need to to able to communicate somehow, like through their SDK or REST API.